# Multiple div creation / destruction bug with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

I'm having a weird but with a mix of CSS3/HTML5/Javascript on Webkit browsers (didn't tried any other though).

Just try this fiddle out:
http://jsfiddle.net/tbergeron/XHQxH/

Hover over multiple "tiles" as fast as you can and you'll see that sometime it stops working.

The javascript code is:

```
 $('.tile').one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    var tile = this;

    // Hide Title label
    $(tile).find('.title').hide();

    var bigTileHtml = '<div class="bigTile">';
    bigTileHtml = bigTileHtml + '<div class="title">Tile Title Holy Cow Yeah</div>';
    bigTileHtml = bigTileHtml + '<div class="description">Tile description goes here.</div>';
    bigTileHtml = bigTileHtml + '</div>';

    // Create a new bigTile
    var bigTile = $(bigTileHtml).appendTo('.tiles');

    // Sets bigTile's position
    var position = $(this).position();
    bigTile.css('top', position.top + 4);
    bigTile.css('left', position.left + 4);

    bigTile.mouseout(function() {
        // Show Title label
        $(tile).find('.title').show();
        bigTile.remove();
    });

    bigTile.show();
});
```

For the HTML/CSS (which is a bit less useful for diagnostic) please check the fiddle I linked up there.

EDIT: The problem seems to be that "webkitTransitionEnd" only gets fired once. So next time the transition ends, nothing gets called. I'm wondering: **Is there any way to reset this behavior so that when it ends, it resets and can be fired again?**

So to resume, when you hover over many tiles multiple times, it stops displaying the pink div.

Thanks for the help to anybody who can take some time to help me.

/tommy

Comment: What's supposed to be happening I hover and hover and nothing happens...

Comment: @elclanrs try clicking on it.

Comment: I see now, it only works on Chrome for me, FF doesn't. I re-read the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pink div only displays once because your function is only called once for each tile. This is because you are using the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler.

Your code does the following:

- On tile hover it performs a css animation
- Once the animation is finished the event listener function is triggered (but only the first time the animation ends for each tile)
- Your event listener function creates the pink tile and adds an event listener to this new tile to be triggered when the cursor leaves the tile
- When this function is triggered the pink tile is deleted

All of this can be achieved with just css3. I have updated your jsfiddle code to show you how to do this with just css3 using hovers and transitions. Then some javascript can be used to update the content of the hover tile dynmically if you like as: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XHQxH/9/

Comment: I think there would be a much better way to achieve what you want to do. Would you like to explain what you are trying to achieve and we can try help you do this in a better way.

Comment: Wow thanks! You are totally right. I'm trying to make a tile based interface with tiles zooming in on hover. Each tiles will contain a text title. When they get hovered another div appears over the zoomed one with more detailed content. That explains the div switch. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please see the edited answer above with a link to an updated version of your code.

Comment: this is really cool but only reason why I was creating a new DIV is because I'll need to put a lot of stuff in it like images, maybe even an audio player at some point. So I'll need a way to dynamically manipulate stuff inside the div that's why also everything was "absolute". Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: THAT is the "bug" "(but only the first time the animation ends for each tile)". Why so?! This is dumb. Is there a way to reset this?

Comment: I've update the answer and code to do this. Please have a look. I hope this helps.